# View variable at exception

Tags: java, android

I am trying my first attempt at debugging an android java application using Android Studio. I have never used a debugger for java before so I don't know what to expect.

What I am used to is using a debugger in c++ in a NativeActivity in android. When an application crashes I get a stack trace. I am them able to inspect the methods in the stack trace and observe their variables.

Can this be done in Java on android?

Example. I am getting an exception: index out of bounds. When it crashes without the debugger attached, it give me a stack trace, and I can navigate through the stack trace in code.

But when I attach the debugger, no stack trace shows at all and I can not inspect variables. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are backwards. The stacktrace should be available when **it is connected**

Comment: Precisely the source of my confusion.... :P

Answer (score 0):

My flow is to put break point after I checked stack trace and look for line to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When the debugger is attached it automatically pauses the execution when an unhandled exception ocurres.

But you're interested in the variables of your own code so you have to **place a breakpoint** before the **line where the exception was thrown**.

In Android Studio you should now be able to view the variables in the "Debug" view (on the bottom of the screen - at least in the default configuration). 
You can even execute other statements in the "Debug" view while the breakpoint is still pausing the execution.